# Binding onclick to element calls the method in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div>Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button  type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button id="btn-accept" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Accept</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I show it from a function in javascript:

```
function foo(param1, param2){

    $("#btn-accept").bind('click', bar(param1, param2)) ;
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
}
```

When I do the binding to the `#btn-accept` it already calls the method. How can I avoid this?

Comment: I changed the `foo1` to `bar`, I hope you don't mind but at a quick glance it looked like you were calling `foo` instead of a different method

Comment: Try replacing `$("#btn-accept").bind('click', bar(param1, param2)) ;` with `$("#btn-accept").bind('click', () => {bar(param1, param2)}) ;`

Comment: This might not be what you want as you'd have to change the function but you can add to `event.data` [like so](http://api.jquery.com/bind/#passing-event-data)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap it in a function like so:

```
function foo(param1, param2){
    $("#btn-accept").bind('click', function() {
        bar(param1, param2);
    });
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
}
```

Comment: @PabloCasas Because in your original code you were executing the function so the second parameter of `.bind` was actually being set to the result of `bar`, here they are passing a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should bind event like this.

```
function foo(param1, param2){

    $("#btn-accept").bind('click', function() {
        bar(param1, param2);
    });
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to the event handler:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '"#btn-accept"', {'param1' : 'abc', 'param2' : 'cde' }, bar);
```

Then in your function:

```
function bar( event ) {
  alert( "param1 " + event.data.param1 );
}
```